# Compiler error when moving C++ main method to its own file

Tags: c++, g++, program-entry-point

I have the world's easiest program here. I'd imagine it'd only take a second for some of you to figure out what's wrong.

foo.h:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

namespace foo
{
    char str[ 20 ];

    void bar(char* s);
}

#endif
```

foo.cpp:

```
#include "foo.h"

using namespace std;

namespace foo
{
    void bar(char* s) {
        return;
    }
}
```

foo_main.cpp:

```
#include "foo.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace foo;

int main(void)
{
    bar( str );
}
```

Now when I try to compile these three together:

```
g++ foo_main.cpp foo.cpp -o foo

/tmp/cc22NZfj.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `foo::str'
/tmp/ccqMzzmD.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I want to be using str as a global within the namespace foo, so that needs to be left there. If I move my main method into foo.cpp then things compile fine. What do I do if I want to leave my main method in a separate file? As you can see, I even put include guards on the .h file so that there wouldn't be a conflict with str, but doesn't seem to be working. What's wrong?

Comment: Include guards help if the same header is `#include`d twice **in the same source file**. It doesn't help when a header defines something and then gets included in more than one source file.

Comment: +1 for a damn well asked question. You could have reduced even more but let’s not be picky.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just like any other global, declare it wherever you need to use it and define it in one place only. So in `foo.h`, mark it as `extern`. Then define it in `foo.cpp`.

Answer (score 3):

The include directive includes the contents of the included file literally into the file containing the `#include`. Thus you end up with the definition `char str[ 20 ];` in *both* cpp files, hence twice.

Write

```
extern char str[ 20 ];
```

in the header file and put

```
char str [ 20 ];
```

into only one of the cpp files.